# Unity: need help exporting FBX model from android target at runtime

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, autodesk, fbx

I have been working on a runtime FBX exporter for unity. It uses the Autodesk FBX SDK, which asks for you to have RUNTIME_FBX in the scripting define symbols of the project in order to be built and ran on a target.

I have this defined in the the settings and it works with a desktop build. But once I switch the target to android (for VR), the build fails because it no longer can recognize classes from the Autodesk FBX SDK library.

Has anyone ran into problems with this or no what to do to get the library detected?

Or if this is somehow not possible, is there a recommended format for exporting at runtime on android from a unity app?

Answer (score 0):

FBX file format is not public, only with fbx sdk could be read. Unity 3D also uses fbx sdk.
According to [this](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fbx-forum/android-version-of-fbx-sdk/m-p/6819894#M8606):

```
Unfortunately there are no plans to port the FBX SDK to work on Android at this time.
```

So Unity3D can not support fbx on Android.